# Issue with QGIS 3.4.4 Atlas legend not showing all map items

Tags: qgis, cartography, legend, atlas

I have a layer within my project that has been filtered to show the associated point with the associated Atlas feature:

[image: Rule-based filter for atlas]

But when in composer view and there are both point types within an Atlas preview these point types do not appear in the legend.

[image: Atlas view with both point types but not in legend]

They are also not present in the item properties for the legend.

[image: PAO_SoBI_LB_RA should have two types of points]

Do I need to be filtering the legend?

Comment: What happens if you check the "Auto Update" box in the upper left?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Check that the legend is associated with the main map and not your overview under Item Properties for the legend (see circled drop down list below)

[image]

2. Try to manually add the layer using the plus sign and turn filtering on and off to see if it turns up.
3. If not, you may need to manually recreate another legend (I have had this problem with legend items not showing up in the filtered view because I have used a legend from a template).

Comment: It is associated with the main map. I have just added the layers manually, but the filtering button seems to have no effect and still not present in the legend.I am unclear about what is meant by 'manually recreate legend'. Would this involve coding or just delete this legend and start the process again?

Comment: I mean to delete the legend and try again, yes.

Comment: I did delete the legend and start again, but still encountered the same problem.